How can i get this url if im in aws academy labs? https://<YOUR_SUBDOMAIN>.awsapss.com/start
The point is to activate toolkit aws in visual studio 2022.
I tried to create a new iam user but i don't have permissions. Im looking for that url but when i click it nothing happens. Thanks for the help.
enter image description here

Are you sure it uses SSO as the authentication type? If it does, it will be the same URL you use to login to the web console.

Don't use IAM Identity Center. It is for Single Sign-On, which you probably don't want to use. Try another option.
